# Cannot Get Custom Quick Action to the src folder using eclipse

Tags: force.com-sites, salesforce1-app, metadata

I have created two object-specific Actions on my Custom Object, I was trying to sync over the new quick actions that I have created to my src code using eclipse and force.com plugin.
I can see those quickactions on the Metadata Components like below.
[image]

However, when I try to refresh from the server, both actions do not appear in the src folder.
If I check there system quickactions like 'LogACall', a global action, it will get refreshed to my local without problem.
Any idea why system is not recognizing my custom quick actions?

Comment: After further looking into this problem, I noticed that 'NewAlbum' and 'NewJobNote' are actions on my custom objects. However, if I create an global action it will sync over without problem

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same problem using salesforce-ant.

The problem is the following, and I think is a bug in the metadata api.

To get the list of metadata item, you need to call metadata api method:

```
DescribeMetadataResult[] = metadataConnection.describeMetadata(double apiVersion)
```

With this result you get a list of metadata types, for example: CustomField, QuickAction, etc.

With that list, you are able to get the members for each of them using one call per type:

```
ListMetadataQuery query = new ListMetadataQuery();
query.setType(s);
FileProperties[] lmr = mc.listMetadata(new ListMetadataQuery[] { query }, asOfVersion);
```

Now we can compare the result for CustomField and for QuickAction

CustomField example:

```
fullName = Account.Overall_Segment__c
type = CustomField
```

QuickAction example:

```
fullName = Send_Invoice
type = QuickAction
```

As you can see, the QuickAction is missing the target object, in this example "Account"

Therefore, to retrieve the source, in your case the Eclipse plugin, will do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Send_Invoice</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account.Overall_Segment__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>30.0</version>
</Package>
```

the following Package xml will fail to retrieve the QuickAction, and success to retrieve the Account object containing the custom field Overall_Segment__c.

This is the root of the problem. I don't you Eclipse, but I build a tool on top of the Metadata API, and this is affecting the deployments of QuickActions.

The solution to this is to add the "target object" before the QuickAction name. But how can you get the target object?

Well, is possible a workaround, but absolutely inefficient, you need to use this call for each ObjectType, this could mean hundreds or thousands of objects ....

```
DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult [] = connection.describeAvailableQuickActions(string parentOrContextType );
```

The real solution, is to ask Salesforce Metadata API team to include the object name before the name of the action, just like they include the name of the object before the name of the field.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue myself as well. The problem, as @larsenfed suggested, is due to the fact that the metadata API is not properly returning the parent object in the `fullName` for each [`QuickAction`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_quickaction.htm). On top of that, as you noted, global actions require no object and are pulled down properly.

Imagine a scenario where you have 3 custom publisher actions, `Send_Note`, `Request_Feedback`, `Submit_Application`. Send_Note is a global publisher action, but `Request_Feedback` and `Submit_Application` live on a custom object called `New_Applicant__c`. [Eclipse](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE), [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/), even the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) will suggest you create the following package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Request_Feedback</members>
        <members>Send_Note</members>
        <members>Submit_Application</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <version>31.0</version>
</Package>
```

Everything you read makes this seem like the right package.xml file. However, you look at your code that you just pulled down, and you see the following:

[image: Missing Publisher Actions]

Where is `Request_Feedback` or `Submit_Application`? Well unfortunately the package.xml file is **wrong**. Object specific publisher actions require that the object name be before the [Publisher Action](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm&language=en_US) full name, similar to how you would for a custom field. Let's make some quick modifications to our package.xml to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>New_Applicant__c.Request_Feedback</members>
        <members>Send_Note</members>
        <members>New_Applicant__c.Submit_Application</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <version>31.0</version>
</Package>
```

Notice how all we did was prepend the object name to the fullName. When we pull the code down again, we get all of the publisher actions properly, as originally expected.

[image: All Publisher Actions]

Unfortunately this requires some manual work when dealing with an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) but hopefully in the future Salesforce will modify the Metadata API to properly pull down the fullName.

Comment: I just ran into this problem with the recruiting app.  The fix is (poorly formatted)........

    <types>
        <members>Candidate__c.New_Application</members>
        <members>Employment_Website__c.New_Posting</members>
        <members>Job_Application__c.New_Review</members>
        <members>New_Application</members>
        <members>New_Candidate</members>
        <members>New_IT_Position</members>
        <members>New_Standard_Position</members>
        <members>Position__c.New_Posting</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>

Answer (score 0):

In the package.xml file under "src" in Eclipse, you will have to add the QuickAction metadata type and the name of the QuickAction.

E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>test1</members>
    <members>test2</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>...</members>
    <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
</types>
.
.
.
<types>
    <members>Account.New_Quote</members>
    <members>Opportunity.New_Quote</members>
    <name>QuickAction</name>
</types>
<version>41.0</version>
```

In the above example, you can see the pattern to fetch the QuickAction, i.e., **ObjectAPIName.QuickActionName**.